# why in react js showing index.html tags for seo if we navigating to other pages?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, seo

I am new in react js trying to set SEO for website but it's showing me index.html tags first after that what ever i set in  tag that showing below in the head tag i want show only particular meta tags for that page...how to do that in react js please help me out....

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In React the most preferred way to do SEO is using `react-helmet`

Try [react-helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet) to set your SEO tags in react app.

Also remove all SEO from index.js

The code is pretty straight forward.

```
import React from "react";
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";

class Application extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
        <div className="application">
            <Helmet>
                <meta charSet="utf-8" />
                <title>My Title</title>
                <link rel="canonical" href="example.com" />
            </Helmet>
            ...
        </div>
    );
  }
};
```

**Features for React helmet**

- Supports all valid head tags: title, base, meta, link, script, noscript, and style tags.
- Supports attributes for body, html and title tags.
- Supports server-side rendering.
- Nested components override duplicate head changes.
- Duplicate head changes are preserved when specified in the same component (support for tags like "apple-touch-icon").
- Callback for tracking DOM changes.

Comment: then no need to add meta tags in index.html file used this react-helmet ? for all component???

Comment: If you are adding meta tags via `react-helmet` from ALL pages you don't need to add any in index.html

Comment: Note that this is more-or-less useless without implementing server-side rendering.